# Isolate memory usage by process before crash/restart

Tags: arch-linux, kde, manjaro

I'm experiencing crashes (~.5 per day). Memory usage goes from about 40% to 100% without anything launched in a second or two and the machine freezes. I've no time to react. No swap being used. I'd like to review logs on what's causing this but I'm unsure where to find memory usage logs with segregated processes.

Comment: You should make sure the hardware is okay first. Try restarting and running a memory test.

Comment: @gerhardd.Ran memtest and there's no issues. I should note that the machine doesn't hang completely as it would with faulty memory, I have memory usage indicator visible and it shows 99.9% before the system becomes almost completely unresponsive, the mouse still moves with a 30 second delay. But I'm unable to launch htop or anything else.

Comment: Is this a local machine? If so, you may switch to a text console ([CTRL-ALT-F1]) and run `top` with virtual mem based sorting (see the manual). If that does not help, you may need to track it down analytically: when does it happen, is there someone logged on ... etc. Also: Is the swap space deactivated, or really just not used?

Comment: Local machine, tried switching to a different tty and run top previously but since the machine slowed down so much, it never got to launch top in 5 minutes or so. Swap not used as the machine has 16gb of RAM. I only used Brave and VSCodium when it happened.

Comment: I suggest to adjust `/etc/limits.conf` according to your needs and reboot. (https://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf). Set memory limits to half of your RAM, so you will see which process gets killed in the `syslog`.

Comment: Thanks, will try that. It hasn't occurred now in many days.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something I did some years ago to gather data on some servers with rapid spikes in memory usage.  My servers were doing this over a short number of minutes, so this technique was able to capture the data.  It may not be as useful for you if your memory usage spikes happen in mere seconds.

I used `top` in batch mode to write the top 30 processes according to their memory usage to a file, every 15 seconds.  After a memory spike incident, the file showed me which processes experienced growth in memory use and roughly how fast they climbed:

```
LINES=30 COLUMNS=160 top -b -c -o RES -d 15 -n 40 -w  >> /path/to/output.txt
```

**Options:**
`top` has a few quirks about how it handles the number of processes it reports and how much of each process's command line it shows.  The `COLUMNS` and `ROWS` variables are part of this and I explain them with the `-w` option at the end:

- `-b` selects batch mode, where the summary block of lines and the per-process lines are output with no highlighting and no pagination so they'll append to the output file properly.
- `-c` toggles the display of the command in the per-process lines.  Typically `top` is configured to show the base command (like `unattended-upgrades`) for each process, and `-c` will change to showing full command lines with arguments (like `/usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/unattended-upgrades/...`). This can be useful if you have two or three java processes on the server, as I did, and need to know which of them has the memory spikes.
- `-o RES` sorts the per-process lines according to usage of memory, from largest to smallest.  Memory is given in KiB.  An altervative is `-o %MEM` giving the memory usage in percentage of the total memory.
- `-d 15` delays 15 seconds between each check of processes (and burst of output lines).  This means `top` checks four times per minute.
- `-n 40` selects 40 samples and then the `top` command quits.  40 total samples at 4 per minute means top runs for 10 minutes and quits.
- `-w` selects "wide" (long) lines for each process, so the command arguments won't be truncated. `-w` can take an argument specifying the columns, but when I did this, `top` would write a line for **all** the processes and not just the top 30 processes.  Keeping `-w` bare and prefixing the `top` command with `LINES=30 COLUMNS=160` made top show wide lines and only the top 30 processes by memory usage.  The man page suggests the `-w` option isn't needed when the `LINES` and `COLUMNS` variables are set, but `top` seemed to ignore `LINES` and output all the processes.  The `-w` option is last because top would complain about an invalid argument if there were other options after it.
  Adjust the `LINES` and `COLUMNS` values as appropriate to your needs, as well as the `-d` and `-n` numbers.

**Other possibly useful options:**

- `-E` changes the memory scale in the summary lines.  `-E m` selects MiB, and `-E g` selects GiB.  Only the summary lines, though, not the per-process lines.
- `-u username` limit the per-process lines to ones running as the user `username`
- `-p pid,pid` limit the per-process lines to the process ids in the list.

The `top` man page has more info on the above options, including other field names for the `-o` option (run `top -O` to see a quick list of field names).

I wrote a script with that top command, and I invoked the script every 10 minutes from cron.  I didn't have to write a shell script that would function as a long-running background process, but I still got the advantages of an already-running process capturing the memory spikes as they happened.

The output file is not easily parsable by software, since each sample will have a block of lines with the summary info, an empty line or two, and the 30 lines for the processes.  But manually examining the file was sufficient for me at the time.  A small win:  The summary lines have a built-in timestamp that's useful for finding the part of the file shortly before a spike incident.

There are very likely other ways to capture the memory consumption of individual processes on a Linux machine, and they may be better than this one.  I'm just passing along an approach that worked for me.  Hope it can be useful for you, too.